# system property is null even if it is defined in command line

Tags: java

I am debugging a problem in a large system. I was able to locate the problem in a rather basic java feature - the application is started with the -D option to specify some system properties. During run-time though, said properties are not set and their values are null.

Trying to reproduce the issue I created the following very simple application:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String propName = "sysprop";
    String propValue = System.getProperty(propName);
    System.out.println(propName + "=" + propValue);
  }
```

I start the application with the following command line and to my surprise got the same result:

> java -cp javaapplication8.jar javaapplication8.JavaApplication8
> -Dsysprop="some value"
>
> sysprop=null

Apparently I am missing something obvious (or lack some basic knowledge) but what is it?

Thank you.

Comment: `java -Dsysprop="some value" -cp javaapplication8.jar javaapplication8.JavaApplication8` Put the -D before the main class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're specifying `-D` *after* the classname, so it's being treated as a regular command line argument to be passed on to the application itself. You would see that if you printed out the values in `args`.

Run the app like this instead:

```
java -cp javaapplication8.jar -Dsysprop="some value" javaapplication8.JavaApplication8
```

*All* arguments which are meant to apply to the environment rather than the application should come before the classname. If you run just `java`, you'll see usage help like this:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include
[...]
```